# Problems accessing disk after IO tests

Tags: hard-drive, ubuntu-18.04, io

I am having problems when accessing my home folder, or generally anything that is on my HDD (I also have an SSD which seems to work fine) in my ubuntu (18.04.4) workstation.

```
:/$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb2       219G  120G   88G  58% /
/dev/sdb1       188M  6.0M  182M   4% /boot/efi
/dev/sda3       1.2T   77M  1.2T   1% /scratch
/dev/sda1       563G   57G  477G  11% /home
(...)
:/$ ls opt/
areca  Druva  intel
:/$ ls home
ls: reading directory 'home': Input/output error
```

The only description of the problem I could get with the diagnosis tools that I found googling my problem seem to indicate that the "device is offline", but then looking for further details online of this problem only gets me to some very system/hardware specific answers that don't seem to apply to my case.

```
:/$ dmesg
...
[784771.325306] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[784771.325464] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[784771.325483] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
```

I believe this is related with some testing I was doing in read/write speeds, for which I had to flush the system caches in order to obtain more reliable results, and I was doing this in a systematic way by running the following script:

```
$ cat flush.sh 
#!/bin/bash

sudo su -c "sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```

For more precise testing, I also did some trials splitting these two commands into two separate bashscripts to time them separatedly and I believe this is what caused the problem.

Does anybody know what might have happened and how could I fix this? (also, if possible, considering that I am working remotely with a computer to which I have no physical access)

EDIT: this was the result of running `lsblk`:

```
:/$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
(...other "loop" drives...)
sda      8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 572.2G  0 part /home
├─sda2   8:2    0    61G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda3   8:3    0   1.2T  0 part /scratch
sdb      8:16   0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   190M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sdb2   8:18   0 223.4G  0 part /
```

I tried to `unmount` the disk to run `fsck`, succeeded on the first but failed on the second. `lsblk` now shows the following:

```
:/$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
(...other drives...)
sda      8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 572.2G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0    61G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda3   8:3    0   1.2T  0 part
```

When I run `sudo fdisk -l`, it shows the info for `sdb` but nothing for `sda`, and when I try to mount `sda1` and `sda3` I get the following errors respectively:

```
mount: /home: /dev/sda1 already mounted or mount point busy.
mount: /scratch: /dev/sda3 is not a valid block device.
```

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: Not really. Although I know this is the zero test for all informatic related stuff, not being able to physically access the machine makes me VERY paranoid that any hang during the reboot process might end up just making the machine unreachable and that is game over. I would like to try any other diagnostic thing before doing this, if possible.

Comment: Can you `unmount` it? Can you run `fsck` on the filesystem? Are you sure that your speed tests didn't write all over your mounted filesystem? What's the output of `lsblk`, and does `dmesg` say anything about `sda` going away / coming back in another slot? What about `ls /scratch` (also on `sda`)?

Comment: I updated the post with the results for unmounting, `fsck` and `lsblk`. The filesystem doesn't seem to be full from the result of `df -h`, so it doesn't look like it is that. As far as I can see of the `dmesg` log, there is nothing like you say for `sda` (there is a message that says the following, but I don't know what it means: `EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_find_entry:1454: inode #18616228: comm inSync: reading directory lblock 0`), and yes, I had the exact same problems with `/scratch`.